# How to put a TEXTVIEW center on a IMAGEVIEW in Android Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I would like to know, how I can a put a text center on a image, here is the sample image,

[image]

I tried the below code, but its not working fine,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/points"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="+2"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btbt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/btbt" />
         </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>      
</LinearLayout>
```

Please let me know a good solution.

Comment: Instead of an ImageView, you could use that drawable in your TextView's background attribute. You would help flattening your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating a textview with a background image.  Something like:

```
        <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Random Text"
        android:background="@drawable/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Placing TextView on ImageView. Not setting background for textView.

Comment: True, but it accomplished what the OP wanted as it was the accepted answer.  It just goes to show that there is more than one way to accomplish a task.

Answer (score 2):

you can use an imagebutton for this purpose 
i will prefer using imagebutton
.. or 
put this imageview in this order

```
<TableRow 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Relativelayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/points"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="+2"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btbt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/btbt" />
</Relativelayout >
         </TableRow>
```